# Oracle.DataAccess memory leak

Tags: vb.net, oracle10g, windbg

I am supporting and developing an ASP.NET application, which connects to a few SQL databases and a few Oracle databases.  After a period of time (sometimes a day and sometimes a week and sometimes a few weeks), the W3WP.exe process memory increases above 1GB.

At this point I am unable to connect to the Oracle databases (Out of memory Exception or OracleException is thrown when trying to connect to an Oracle database), but I am able to connect to the SQL databases.

I use Oracle.DataAccess to connect to the Oracle database (version 10.2.0.100).  I have come accross a few web pages, which talk about memory leaks with this third party API and my version specifically e.g. here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1060230.

I am planning to upgrade to the next version.  Has anyone else had any memory leak types problems with this API?

Comment: Why is this tagged as "windbg"? Are you looking for input on how to troubleshoot the possible memory leak?

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen, sorry for the delay responding.  Yes, I am.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen, the process increases to about 1 GB and at that point I am unable to connect to any Oracle databases.  Do you have any suggestions? Could you post an answer so that I can give credit?